# Drop down list in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
    <% form.inputs do %>
      <% @account.account_preference.editorial_attributes.each do |key, value| %>
        <%= account_pref.input "editorial_#{key}".to_sym, :as => :radio, :collection => options_for(Editorial, key.to_sym), :wrapper_html => { :class => "compact" }, :label => key.titleize  %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

How do a change this drop down list to a regular drop down list with out radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
account_pref_options = []
@account.account_preference.editorial_attributes.each do |k,v|
  account_pref_options << [k.titleize, "editorial_#{key}"]
end
```

Then use the select tag helper. If within a `form_for model do |f|` tag, do

```
<%= f.select :field_name, account_pref_options_options %>
```

If witin a `form_tag` tag, do

```
<%= select_tag(:field_name, options_for_select(account_pref_options)) %>
```

Check out the EdgeGuides for more information as well as the RoR API.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags